# Display Text Input Default Value

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a phone number  for different store .  I want to pull the information from the default value of each store number and display it in a column .  I was able to pull the first information ( Orlando ) with this Jquery script .

/* Store Number Orlando */

```
var StoreNumValue = $("#input_15_40").val();
$( "#fenceDisplayStoreNum" ).text(StoreNumValue);
});
```

But when I change Store City from the dropdown , it doesn't pull the information anymore .
Everytime I added this script from the code above .

/* Store Number Oviendo */

```
var StoreNumValue = $("#input_15_41").val();
$( "#fenceDisplayStoreNum" ).text(StoreNumValue);
});
```

What am I missing .

P.S.
`#fenceDisplayStoreNum` is the CSS ID I assigned to the text widget in Elementor .
`#input_15_41 , #input_15_40"` is the CSS ID of the form fields .
Any help is greatly appreciated .   Thanks !

Comment: Well did you even add event listener on change for the drop-down because i don't see it? And anyway, no one can help you with guessing without seeing [mre]

Comment: To be honest I am really fairly new to JQuery . 
Will the link of the said page be helpful if I send it out ?

[CLICK ME](https://orlandoprintcompany.com/business-cards-fence-outlet-v3/)

As you can see , when you change the dropdown from the city , there is a different value for store number . 

How can I achieve , that every time a user change city , the display in the right side will also change . 

Thanks .

Hoping you can help me with all this I can provide .

Comment: From what I can see changing Choose Your Location and then next drop-down always changes the phone number...

Comment: @ikiK Yes . And I want to display the default value of that in the right side .

Comment: I dont understand, the defoult value is for example: `<option value="South Daytona ,">South Daytona ,</option>` and in phone number  accordingly is: `(386) 267-6760  South Daytona` , I still dont understand the problem.

Comment: I'll try my best to explain what I want to achieve .

Please see attached image

[CLICK FOR IMAGE](https://imgur.com/tOSALFF)

I want the default value of each store locations number to be displayed into the right side .

Comment: @ikiK 

Please help . :(

Comment: I understand now, but this is turned to be a bit complicated cose the way this CMS of your is working. If you check the source, every time you you pick something, corresponding input is shown, and other is hidden, every one of them has its own ids, so you can not target then directly to get the value. Its first time i see system like this. So you would need to find a way that every time you set the coast or change the city - to get city value, then loop and search phone number inputs and find the corresponding one to get its value and then apply it to desired field.

Comment: Doe he terrible design markup this is tedious work and it does not have easy/fast solution. I don't have time nor will to write that now.

Comment: @ikiK Is it really that complicated ?

Comment: Yes, I just told you to check your source code, there are numerous hidden input fields that change states based on selections of two drop-downs (those also change ids and visibility states). I cheeked, they don't have common CSS classes to target them, I said what I would do, you have better idea? If it would be one input field to target, it would be easy, well. its not. Every time you select something, it changes the input field itself, the id, the visibility. What to target then?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your page.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
// when document is ready
    jQuery("#input_15_18, #input_15_3, #input_15_17").change(function() {
        // fetch Coast, East coast city and West coast city selects and add event listener on change
        // for each change call function callgetPhone
        return callgetPhone () +
               callgetPhone () + 
               callgetPhone ();
    })
});

function callgetPhone (){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
            getPhone () // call getPhone function
        }, 500); // use timeout due the CMS processing of filling the Store Phone field
}

function getPhone () {
    let allLables = jQuery( "#gform_15" ).find("label.gfield_label")
    // Get all labels in order too find currently active Store Phone
        allLables.each(function( index ) {
        // for each label
        if (jQuery( this ).html()==="Store Phone") {
            // if it has Store Phone text
            let phone = jQuery( this ).next().find("input:not(:disabled)").val()
            // find input next to it that is not disabled and save its value
            jQuery("#fenceDisplayStoreNum").find('p').html(phone);
            // Set east phone
            let west = jQuery("div[data-id=c93f33e]");
            jQuery(west[0]).find("p").text(phone);
            jQuery(west[1]).find("p").text(phone);
            // Set west phone
        }
    });
}
```

Also just to note: this is not free coding writing service, so don't get use to help like this. As you are new here I helped, hope you will learn from this, I added notes and explained in comments of question what needs to be done.

Welcome to SO.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs !

Comment: @coatedpiLL np, please consider checking this answer on ✔︎ button as accepted, to mark this question as solved, if this solved the problem...